# Kernels of seminorms

Tags: functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

Suppose $p_1,\cdots, p_n: X \to \mathbb{R}$ are seminorms defined on a vector space $X$, and $q$ is another non-zero seminorm such that
$$\{0\}\neq \bigcap_{i=1}^n \text{Ker}(p_i)\subset \text{Ker}(q).$$
Can we conclude $q\leq c_1 p_1 +\cdots c_n p_n$, for some reals $c_1, \cdots, c_n \geq 0$? Here $p_i$'s are linearly independent and $c_i$'s are not all zeros. Are there counterexamples?

Comment: A counterexample would be $n=1$, $p_1(x)=\|x\|$, $q (x)=|f(x)|$ where $f$ is linear and unbounded/discontinuous.

Comment: @daw Thanks! I only saw your comment after editing my question. If the kernels aren't allowed to be trivial, can there still be counterexamples??

Comment: @daw I just realized, we can always quotient out the intersection, and on the quotient space, it then becomes a norm and a seminorm, and your conterexample still works.